# Having Issues with an AssertionError when trying to use the psd() command in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, psd

I'm trying to write a short script that takes a .csv file with some distance data, and outputs the psd file for it. the code is here:

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

name = raw_input('File:')

data = open(name + '.csv', 'r')
distances = []

for row in data:
    distances.append(row.replace("\n",""))

for i in range(len(distances)):
    distances[i] = float(distances[i])

Pxx, freqs = plt.psd(distances, NFFT=16,Fs=2,detrend='detrend_mean',window='window_none',noverlap=128,sides='onesided',scale_by_freq=True)

plot(Pxx,freqs)
plt.savefig(name + 'psd.png', bbox_inches = 'tight')
```

As you can see, it's pretty simple. the csv file just features one column of numbers, so distances is a vector.

The error I'm getting is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:psdplot.py", line 15, in <module>
    Pxx, freqs = plt.psd(distances, NFFT=16,Fs=2,detrend='detrend_mean',window='window_none',noverlap=128,sides='onesided',scale_by_freq=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 3029, in psd
    sides=sides, scale_by_freq=scale_by_freq, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 8696, in psd
    sides, scale_by_freq)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mlab.py", line 389, in psd
    scale_by_freq)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mlab.py", line 423, in csd
    noverlap, pad_to, sides, scale_by_freq)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mlab.py", line 251, in _spectral_helper
    assert(len(window) == NFFT)
AssertionError
```

Could someone direct me on how to fix this? I'm sure it's rather obvious, but I haven't been able to find anything on fixing it in this particular context.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you're going to have to post some of your data. right now, no one can rerun your example.

Comment: another comment: never change elements of the array when you're iterating over them. you should combine your first two loops. e.g., `distances.append(float(row.replace("\n","")))`

Comment: Here's one of my files: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=01742044401291690559

If you would prefer a different host I can use that one instead.

I'll make the suggested edit, thanks!

Comment: Just copy paste some code that loads a hard-coded subset of the data and reproduces your problem. Hint: use the StringIO module.